# Chialisp environment set up

Tags: python, blockchain

I'm following along with this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8Thrrw25rQ&list=PLmnzWPUjpmaGzFNq2PeMljHNrXGwj2TDY&index=1

trying to set up my dev environment for chialisp.

Installed python, created virtual environment, ran pip install chia-dev-tools (got this working after installing c++ buildtools). All looks to work fine but when i run the chia --help command I'm getting errors

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
File "", line 88, in *run_code
File "C:\chialisp\chiatest1\venv\Scripts\chia.exe_*main**.py", line 4, in 
File "C:\chialisp\chiatest1\venv\Lib\site-packages\chia\cmds\chia.py", line 18, in 
from chia.cmds.peer import peer_cmd
File "C:\chialisp\chiatest1\venv\Lib\site-packages\chia\cmds\peer.py", line 7, in 
from chia.cmds.cmds_util import NODE_TYPES
File "C:\chialisp\chiatest1\venv\Lib\site-packages\chia\cmds\cmds_util.py", line 17, in 
from chia.rpc.wallet_rpc_client import WalletRpcClient
File "C:\chialisp\chiatest1\venv\Lib\site-packages\chia\rpc\wallet_rpc_client.py", line 3, in 
from chia.data_layer.data_layer_wallet import Mirror, SingletonRecord
File "C:\chialisp\chiatest1\venv\Lib\site-packages\chia\data_layer\data_layer_wallet.py", line 42, in 
from chia.wallet.outer_puzzles import AssetType
File "C:\chialisp\chiatest1\venv\Lib\site-packages\chia\wallet\outer_puzzles.py", line 8, in 
from chia.wallet.cat_wallet.cat_outer_puzzle import CATOuterPuzzle
File "C:\chialisp\chiatest1\venv\Lib\site-packages\chia\wallet\cat_wallet\cat_outer_puzzle.py", line 11, in 
from chia.wallet.cat_wallet.cat_utils import (
File "C:\chialisp\chiatest1\venv\Lib\site-packages\chia\wallet\cat_wallet\cat_utils.py", line 24, in 
@dataclasses.dataclass
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\tony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\dataclasses.py", line 1220, in dataclass
return wrap(cls)
^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\tony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\dataclasses.py", line 1210, in wrap
return _process_class(cls, init, repr, eq, order, unsafe_hash,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\tony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\dataclasses.py", line 958, in _process_class
cls_fields.append(_get_field(cls, name, type, kw_only))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\tony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\dataclasses.py", line 815, in _get_field
raise ValueError(f'mutable default {type(f.default)} for field '
ValueError: mutable default <class 'chia.types.blockchain_format.program.Program'> for field limitations_solution is not allowed: use default_factory

Any thoughts on where I might be going wrong??

Answer (score 0):

For future reference I had to run this command

Set-Alias -Name chia "C:\Users[insert user here]\AppData\Local\Programs\Chia\resources\app.asar.unpacked\daemon\chia.exe"